# PHP: Trigger fatal error?

Tags: php, fatal-error

I would like to be able to throw a fatal, uncatchable error in my php class when a user of my class abuses it for something I did not intend. I don't want him/her to be able to recover with a catch clause.
I know about `trigger_error`, but I can only make it issue warnings or notices.

Comment: Why bother? Whoever is implementing your class: 1. Is a programmer. 2. Has access to the source. 3. Can and likely will delete the `trigger_error()` call.

Comment: @Sammitch: I want to make my intentions clear. I want to let whoever uses my code know that what they are doing is not how I intended them to use it. To me throwing an exception sends the message "you deal with this undefined behaviour." I want to send the message: "Don't do it that way, do it this way instead".

Comment: Example libraries. Where you should for example absolutely NOT do something if some condition is not true. (Useful for people who don't like reading documentations :P)

Comment: @bwoebi: Exactly my situation ;-)

Comment: I realize this is a 7 year old question, but even so, someone might come upon it. The idea you had that an exception sends the message to the programmer to deal with undefined behavior is totally wrong. That is not what exceptions mean. The only way the programmer would think that is if they don't know anything about programming or they make random and wild assumptions. Exceptions are just cleaner. Also triggering an error doesn't mean they can't recover from it. They could still use error handling in a similar way to exception handling.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

E_USER_ERROR is the suited constant.

```
trigger_error("Fatal error", E_USER_ERROR);
```

See also the first example of the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) and the [list of PHP Errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) (only ones beginning with E_USER* may be issued from trigger_error).

Comment: very ironic that the guy who said "Useful for people who don't like reading documentations" didn't bother to read the first example of the manual page.

Answer (score 14):

Note:  if you're using a custom error handler (see [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php))
`E_USER_ERROR` will NOT halt/exit/die  unless the error handler returns false

nutshell : your custom error handler effectively determines if `E_USER_ERROR` is treated as a fatal

Comment: Very true.   As I've noted in another place, you can create a fatal error via:

    if($isTestMode==1){
      eval("noSuchFunction();");
    }

This method will always work.

Comment: Thanks Brad this really helped me, I am using custom error handler function. Although it was 'handling the error' I triggered with the flag E_USER_ERROR it was not causing a 'fatal' error until I returned false from  my error handler function.

Answer (score 7):

```
debug_print_backtrace();
trigger_error("As much information as you can provide, please", E_USER_ERROR);
exit();
```

exit() terminates the PHP script entirely.  The more information you can provide users or developers about the error, the better.  Error codes are passé.

Edit: use of E_USER_ERROR should terminate the script anyway, so moved debug_print_backtrace() before trigger_error().

Comment: absolutely, adding die; or exit; command after throwing such error is only way to be almost 100% sure. Only way to escape from it (expect php.ini disabled functions) is [runkit_function_remove](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-remove.php)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP 7 or higher, [Error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.error.php) class works too:

```
$flag = false;

try {
    if ($flag == false) {
        throw new Error('An error occured');
    }
} catch (Error $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

If you put `throw new Error('An error occured');` outside the `Try Catch`, You will get a Fatal Error.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to break our acceptance env. and stumbled upon a nice and simple way to induce a `fatal error`.

Simply call non existent function.
As recommended [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/types-of-errors-in-php#:%7E:text=A%20fatal%20error%20is%20another,compiler%20generates%20a%20fatal%20error.)