# How to resort to default behavior in __call?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a PHP class in which I want to allow only certain private methods to be called from outside of the class. I know that I can use `__call` for this, but I'd like that method to resort to its default behavior (throwing a fatal error) when the method being called is not one of the allowed ones.

So far this is what I'm doing:

```php
public function __call( $name, $arguments ) {
    if ( in_array( $name, $this->allowed_private_methods ) ) {
        return call_user_func_array( array( $this, $name ), $arguments );
    } elseif ( is_callable( array( 'parent', '__call' ) ) ) {
        return parent::__call( $name, $arguments );
    } elseif ( method_exists( $this, $name ) ) {
        trigger_error('Call to private method ' . get_class( $this ) . '::' . $name, E_USER_ERROR );
    } else {
        trigger_error('Call to undefined method ' . get_class( $this ) . '::' . $name, E_USER_ERROR );
    }
}
```

This works but if possible I'd like to get the original native PHP fatal error and not a user error. Is that possible?

Some additional context in case it matters: the environment is WordPress, and what I want is to be able to supply a `[$this, 'handler_method']` style callback to `add_filter` without having to make `handler_method` public (I want methods to be public only when it makes sense to call them on their own, not just as WordPress hook handlers).

Comment: _"Is that possible?"_ - not with `trigger_error`, because as the manual explicitly states, _"it only works with the E_USER family of constants."_ Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/a/50487141/1427878 is any help (you'd still have to set the message to the equivalent of what the "original" fatal error would contain though.)

Comment: Is there a specific reason these methods need to be private?

Comment: @CBroe Indeed, `throw Error` is the way to go, as you say it's not a perfect solution but I guess it gets as close as it can. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisHaas I mention it in the question, but I want methods to be public only when it makes sense to call them on their own, not just as WordPress hook handlers, for readability/maintanability purposes.

Comment: I get it, but I don't get it. But no judgement either. One alternative you might be interested in, however, is capturing `$this` which allows you to invoke a private method: https://3v4l.org/IhKQa

Answer (score 0):

Based on a comment by @CBRoe, using `throw new Error` will indeed throw a fatal error, even though I still need to manually provide the error message. So my adapted code is now:

```php
public function __call( $name, $arguments ) {
    if ( in_array( $name, $this->hook_callback_methods ) ) {
        return call_user_func_array( array( $this, $name ), $arguments );
    } elseif ( is_callable( array( 'parent', '__call' ) ) ) {
        return parent::__call( $name, $arguments );
    } elseif ( method_exists( $this, $name ) ) {
        throw new \Error( 'Call to private method ' . get_class( $this ) . '::' . $name );
    } else {
        throw new \Error( 'Call to undefined method ' . get_class( $this ) . '::' . $name );
    }
}
```